# Windows Phone Emulator7.1 internet not connected

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

I installed Windows Phone SDK7.1 on my windows7 PC. I opened the Windows Phone Emulator 7.1 to test the web page in Windows Phone Emulator IE, but i am not able to connect to the Internet in the Windows Phone Emulator. I am not using proxy and i am using the "Automatically Detect Settings" in Internet Options-->connections---> LAN settings.

Please help me to connect to the internet via the emulator.i am able to connect through internet in android emulator. Thanks in Advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, I found that problem is with my work network. as my network team considered the Win phone emulator as personal device trying to intrude into the network, so they blocked the request from my win phone emulator. so i need to find the MAC address of my emulator and asked them to add to exception for my emulator.

See this Link [Cannot connect to network destinations on a domain or corporate network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_network)